# debian cannot detect HDMI port with nvidia hybrid set up

Tags: linux, debian, multiple-monitors, hdmi, xrandr

On my laptop I have installed `bumblebee-nvidia` (optirun) which works fine when I use only laptop screen.

But when I connect a monitor to HDMI, nothing is changed, `xrandr` (nor `optirun xrandr`) does not even show the HDMI output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
   1920x1080     60.01*+  59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00    59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      59.86    60.00    59.74  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00    59.90    59.82  
   960x540       60.00    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00    59.92    59.57  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       59.51    60.00    58.99  
   640x360       59.84    59.32    60.00
```

I read some hints about using `intel-virtual-output` (or `optirun intel-virtual-output`) which successfully produces `VIRTUAL1` output, but no HDMI still. All of the information I got, started by xrandr properly showing that HDMI output at least exists. Mine does not. The monitor and cable are fine.

**Other info:**

`lspci | grep VGA`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f91 (rev a1)
```

`cat /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "intelgpu0"
    Driver "intel"
    Option "VirtualHeads" "2"
EndSection
```

`cat /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia`:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier  "Layout0"
    Option      "AutoAddDevices" "false"
    Option      "AutoAddGPU" "false"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "DiscreteNvidia"
    Driver      "nvidia"
    VendorName  "NVIDIA Corporation"

    Option "ProbeAllGpus" "false"
    Option "NoLogo" "true"
    Option "UseEDID" "false"
    Option "UseDisplayDevice" "none"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device "DiscreteNvidia"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

On muxed configurations working solution is to use offloading graphics display.

I described this solution in detail here (and added other possible approaches): https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161961/hdmi-monitor-is-not-recognized/1200200#1200200